# Multi-level DI refactoring

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I don't know if this actually qualifies as DI, since I'm not talking about injecting a concrete implementation of an abstract dependency. I'm just talking about injecting stuff that's needed period.

In my game engine, I want to clean up the part that handles the state of the game (menu, stage select, in-game, cutscenes, etc). All of these things implement a common interface. But one of them, in-game, is also referenced specifically as the current level being played.

There are right now 43 references in my project to the current level, as accessed through the game, a singleton. For example, `Game.CurrentGame.CurrentMap.Something`. The references are in screens, entities, behavior components, even in the main form (for debugging tools).

I want to get rid of this reference by injecting everything that's needed. But the CurrentMap itself isn't the desired dependency - other things are being accessed below it. So my initial plan is to go into each place, find the thing that's actually being used, and inject it by adding a parameter to that class constructor. This introduces another dependency one level up, so I repeat the process until everything is finished. But the problem with this is it will introduce a lot more constructor parameters, including in places that aren't using the dependency directly. A lot of classes will wind up accepting a dependency just so they can pass it on to another object below them.

What would be a cleaner alternative to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about a scenario where the dependencies must make their way down through a few layers of objects to get where they are really needed.  This does not need to happen.

If an object creates dependencies itself you end up with this problem.  If objects are given the dependencies it needs by a factory or DI container (which is just a fancy factory) then you will not have this problem.  So to avoid this problem, you need to decide if each class is concerned with game logic or creating classes.

Let's say you have object `a`, which calls object `b`, which calls object `c` and object `c` needs the current level and object `b` does not.

The wrong way to do it is to call `new C(level);` from within `b`.  As you have pointed out, `b` does not need to know about the level so it seems things are getting worse not better.  You have not gone far enough with the dependency injection.  Instead of creating `c` within `b`, just ask for `c` in the constructor of `b`.  Now class `b` only knows about `c` and knows nothing about `level`.

Misko has explained this better than I can here http://misko.hevery.com/2009/03/30/collaborator-vs-the-factory/

Code in the factory looks like this:

```
Level level = new Level();
C c = new C( level );
B b = new B( c );
A a = new A( b );
```

The class B only knows about it's direct collaborators (`c`) and has no dependency on `Level`.  Because we are creating things in the factory, it is not necessary to pass the leaves of the object graph down through the object graph.

If class `B` had the responsibility for creating `c` then it needs to know all about how to make an instance of class `c`.  This is wrong.

Comment: +1 I think if you find yourself injecting something just so you can pass it to the constructor of something else and are not using the thing directly then you should be thinking about passing the something else in instead.

Comment: Could you clarify "just ask for it in the constructor of `b`"? It sounds like `b` still knows about `c`, because it's asking for it. Could you give a code sample?

Answer (score 1):

Look at using a DI Framework, like Castle Windsor, Structuremap or Unity (there are plenty of others that are perfectly solid as well).

The problem you are describing is not the *only* problem that these frameworks solve, but it's a big part of the type of friction that they almost completely eliminate.

The fact that the dependencies are concrete implementations and not higher level abstractions is irrelevant.  See this question (asked by yours truly):

[IOC/DI: Is Registering a Concrete Type a Code Smell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051821/ioc-di-is-registering-a-concrete-type-a-code-smell)

Answer (score 0):

Usually I inject a service that keeps track of the current state:

```
public interface IGameStateTracker
{
    Game CurrentGame {get;}
    GameMap CurrentMap {get;}
}
```

You should only have to inject this service in constructors of classes that will need it directly. I'm afraid I don't fully understand why you're finding that you need to inject things into classes that don't directly need it: this may be a sign that you're not using proper DI patterns. Could you provide some code samples to show an example of this problem?

I second Phil Sandler's point about using a DI framework. It will make life much easier. But it won't make up for using incorrect DI patterns in the first place.